# Need to calculate until a specific date in tableau?

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-columns, calculated-field

There are three columns, date, x, y

I need to calculate the running sum/total of y for a specific date (today's date more specifically). The data is in two datasources and looks like this in first data source.

```
        DATE    X   Z
        5-Sep       
        6-Sep   26  101
        7-Sep   27  100
        8-Sep   28  99
        9-Sep   29  98
        10-Sep  30  98
        11-Sep  30  98
        12-Sep  30  97
        13-Sep  31  96
        14-Sep  32  95
        15-Sep  33  94
        16-Sep  34  93
        17-Sep  35  92
        18-Sep  35  92
```

and like this is second data source

```
        DATE    Y
        5-Sep   166
        6-Sep   182
        7-Sep   130
        8-Sep   93
        9-Sep   107
        10-Sep  95
        11-Sep  128
        12-Sep  173
        13-Sep  154
        14-Sep  136
        15-Sep  79
        16-Sep  61
        17-Sep  156
        18-Sep  66
```

Lets say that today's date is 17th Sep, then I need to calculate the running sum of 'Z' until today and display it next to the 'X' column. Something like this

```
        17-Sep  35  1499.
```

How do I do that?

(I tried using sets with date by limiting the date to today but then the running sum doesn't work, also there are some errors in calculated field which is because the data is in two different sources)

Please ask if need more clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Super store data, I created a date parameter. Then created a calculated field as follows:

```
if [date param] >= [Order Date] then [Sales] end
```

Now this will display sales prior to your selected date parameter. I also created a filter calc to only see data prior to the selected date in the param.

```
[date param]>=[Order Date]
```

Place this in the filter shelf and select True.

Now place date field on Rows and your sales calculated field on Text pill. Right click on it and select Quick Table Calculation > Running Total.

See sample workbook here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p42tx86v4qidlvn/170327%20stack%20question.twbx?dl=0

EDIT:

If you just want to see the total and the date selected, create a calc field for "last" as `last()` then filter that for zero.